# Can setting the layer of an object cause memory issues?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quartz-core

I have the following code in my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.appImageLogo.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;  
cell.appImageLogo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.appImageLogo.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
cell.appImageLogo.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
```

My question is: Can it cause memory issues & if yes, how to release the memory consumed by it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Should be fine. Why would you think it would? Run your code through instruments leaks tool if you suspect leaks. And (esp if non-ARC code), run it through the static analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

If your cell is not reused and cells count is not many , or if your cell is reused , it will not cause memory issues.

if your cell is reused , and if the `cornerRadius` and `borderColor` and so on property is same , you can code in the statement which when the cell is `nil`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YOURSTRING";
    YourCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){

        cell = [[YourCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.appImageLogo.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;  
        cell.appImageLogo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.appImageLogo.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        cell.appImageLogo.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;

        }
        // other different settings for different cells
        return cell;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference in terms of memory. The cell has a layer regardless, and changing properties on that layer doesn't affect memory consumption.

As an aside, what are you setting the border to a clear colour for? Surely that makes no difference to not setting it at all?